# How to set css font-size for text input from style sheet

Tags: css, font-size

I can't set the font-size of a text input from the style sheet. However, it works fine by setting the style attribute.

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text-htmlcharset=utf-; 8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
#about {
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="about" type="input" value="anything" style="font-size:21pt;" />
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work (font-size is ignored):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text-htmlcharset=utf-; 8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
#about {
    font-size:21pt;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="about" type="input" value="anything" />
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? Surely, you're not expected to use inline style for all text inputs? That seems pretty tacky and redundant in some cases. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The value of the `content` attribute in the `meta` tag is malformed; it should be `text/html;charset=utf-8`. Probably not relevant to this question, but surely a problem in cases where the tag would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<style type="text/javascript">` to `<style type="text/css">`

You are confusing the browser because it is looking for JavaScript code, but you are feeding it CSS.  `<script>` tags should be used for javascript, and `<style>` tags for CSS.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo in the example I made. I just fixed the typo, but the issue still exists (even with the correct text/css value)

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue; with `type="text/css"`, everything works for me.  I literally just did a copy paste.  There is no issue.

Comment: @user353885, post the *exact* code you have used, via copy and paste, or, perhaps better here, a URL of your test case that demonstrates the issue. Also please specify the browser(s) you used for testing.

Comment: Sorry again, when fixed my example, it still didn't work. Now it works, so I must be going insane. The full script still doesn't work, but I think the problem is that there's a duplicate #id on another style sheet that is over-writing the font-size. It was just a coincidence that I made a mistake (text/javascript) in my test example that created the exact same behavior. What are the odds of that? I only posted this to stackoverflow, it didn't seem likely that I would make an unrelated mistake that would cause the exact same same odd issue. Anyhow, I'll give you the check for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your style block has a type of text/javascript. Remove that and it'll work fine.